Is it possible to create custom Haskell "toplevels"?
I am writing a compiler in Haskell, trying to shun the lexing and parsing phases. I would like the source code to be an AST implemented as an algebraic type.
My current structure is the following :

I have a set of .hs files that contain the definitions of AST nodes, and the transformation functions from a program to its output, chiefly a monadic function named compile. This is the "compiler implementation".
I have another .hs file that defines a nullary function called program, which returns the AST to compile. This is the "program".
Lastly, I have a last .hs file that defines main basically as compile program. This is the "driver".

I would like to be able to deliver the compiler (compiler implementation + driver) in a neat packaged form, expecting my users to provide the definition of program themselves.
I have tried to implement the compiler with instances of Read for the AST types, but the problem is that the feedback for program error says "couldn't read", and that's it. Since I expect the program to be in the form of valid Haskell, I would like the part that reads the AST to be done with a Haskell compiler.
I imagine a solution where I would be able to provide a beefed up Haskell compiler incorporating the compiler implementation and the driver, which would compile the program.
Is it possible to create this kind of artefact, in the like of a LISP image or an OCaml custom top-level?

I think the simplest solution is just to write a shell script to do this. Are there any reasons you'd want to avoid that?

@Noughtmare: that's what I am already doing. As stated, I would like to deliver a packaged solution, but I just read about the ghci startup script which would load the compiler implementation to be exactly what I am looking for.

I mean the shell script could generate all the required .hs files for your compiler and then call ghc (and finally clean up the files perhaps). That would be mostly self contained.

Well, the program should  not be part of the compiler. Yet, it should be Haskell code. I would like the compiler to be compiled to some extent, and still read the program whose AST is expressed in Haskell. Compiling the compiler takes increasingly more time as the compiler gets more features, and that should not be impacting program compile times.

@LaurentLARIZZA If you make a full package of your compiler (using cabal or stack), it can have a library that exports your compile function. If you then use a GHC environment with your library installed, GHCi will be able to load your pre-compiled compile function from the library without the full overhead of compiling it again.

This is, roughly, what xmonad does, so you could read about how that mechanism works and take inspiration from it. The dyre package attempts to bundle up the technique into a standalone library.
You will need to make a full Haskell compiler -- i.e. GHC -- available to the user as part of your packaging.

About the need of making a full GHC available, I figured as much. Thank you for the pointer to Dyre, I will give it a try, as that looks exactly like what I need, with the added bonus of enabling some context persistence between compiles.

I have to say, dyre perfectly does the trick. I can even use optparser to get the location of the program (a.k.a. custom configuration) as a compiler argument, and design a real standalone compiler look-and-feel. The custom configuration can also be split into multiple Haskell modules, all located in the same directory. In the end, my compiler is in a stack package.
